# trouble with paperclip resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

my image resizing is not work as expected. I have imagemagick installed as well. This is how my images look currently. [image]

I want them all to be the same size images

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default home">
            <div class="panel-heading preview">
                <%= image_tag product.cover_photo(:medium) %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <%= link_to product.name, product %><br/>
                $<%= product.price %> - <%= product.weight %><br/>
                <%= product.strain_type %><br/>
                <%= product.product_type %><br/>
                <span style="color: red;">THC: <%= product.percentage %>%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here my photo.rb file with paperclip

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  # IMAGES FOR PRODUCTS
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "350x350>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/


end
```

I have a method inside my product model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  enum instant: {Instant: 0, Request: 1}




    belongs_to :user
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :guest_reviews , dependent: :destroy

    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

    def cover_photo(size)
    if self.photos.length > 0
      self.photos[0].image.url(size)
    else
      "blank.jpg"
    end
  end

  def thumbnail input
    return self.photos[input].variant(resize: '625x415!').processed
  end

  def average_rating
    guest_reviews.count == 0 ? 0 : guest_reviews.average(:star).round(2).to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: You already defined medium and thumb versions of image , if you upload image which is less then 300x300, you won't get correct size in medium. i guess there should be some validation from rails side related to image size, and second thing, manage image size with css instead of rails side

Comment: If the aspect ratio of the input image is not square, your output images will not be square, even if you tell it 100x100>. This is because imagemagick resizes to preserve aspect ratio. So if you want the output to be square, you need to pad it out to square after the resize by using -background white -gravity center -extent 100x100 (or the equivalent in your tool). You can change white to transparent if you want no background to show.

Answer (score 0):

using trailing (#) your image will be centrally cropped, ensuring the requested dimensions.

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  # IMAGES FOR PRODUCTS
  has_attached_file :image,
    styles: { medium: "350x350#", thumb: "100x100#" },
    convert_options: { :thumb => "-quality 60 -strip" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

additional note:

- when you convert you can set quality with `convert_options` to make it smaller and load faster
- although there is option to fit the image but something the result 
  is not good especially if the photo not **same dimensions** for example if someone upload 
  photo with 1000 x 500 then the result mostly not good